# PHP JSON Array decode and store data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am decoding JSON array and then using foreach to loop through after that inserting data to mysql... but always getting "Cannot save data" !

see below php script to know what i have tried yet:

```
<?php

$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("test");

$raw_json = <<<EOT
{"data":[
{"PersonName":"first user","PersonEmail":"first@user.tld"},
{"PersonName":"second user","PersonEmail":"second@user.tld"}
]}
EOT;

// $raw_json = $_POST["allData"]; -- passing parameter

$json = json_decode($raw_json);
// echo json_encode($json); --- getting

foreach($json->data as $item){
// echo json_encode($item); --- getting
  $strPersonName = $item->PersonName;
// echo json_encode($strPersonName); --- getting
  $strPersonEmail = $item->PersonEmail;
// echo json_encode($strPersonEmail); --- getting

/*** Insert ***/
$strSQL = "insert into person (PersonName,PersonEmail)
values (
'".$strPersonName."',
'".$strPersonEmail."',
)
";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if(!$objQuery)
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "0";
$arr['Message'] = "Cannot save data";   
}
else
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "1";
$arr['Message'] = "Data stored successfully";
}
}

mysql_close($objConnect);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

and when i use below php script, i am able to store data to server, check this:

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("test");

$_POST["sPersonName"] = "demo";
$_POST["sPersonEmail"] = "deom@demo.tld";

$strPersonName = $_POST["sPersonName"];
$strPersonEmail = $_POST["sPersonEmail"];

/*** Insert ***/
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO person (PersonName, PersonEmail) 
    VALUES (
        '".$strPersonName."',
        '".$strPersonEmail."'
        )
    ";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if(!$objQuery)
{
    $arr['StatusID'] = "0"; 
    $arr['Message'] = "Cannot save data!";  
}
else
{
    $arr['StatusID'] = "1"; 
    $arr['Message'] = "Data stored successfully";   
}

/**
    $arr['StatusID'] // (0=Failed , 1=Complete)
    $arr['Error'] // Error Message
*/

mysql_close($objConnect);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

So what could be the reason? why i am not able to store data to mysql table, when i am decoding json array ?

Comment: so what's the exact problem what php/mysql errors are you getting?

Comment: Please, _please_, ***please*** [Read the READ BOX](http://php.net/mysql_query): `mysql` is deprecated. Stop using it. Use an extension that supports _prepared statements_ if you even remotely care about injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma after the last value...

Change

```
$strSQL = "insert into person (PersonName,PersonEmail)
values (
'".$strPersonName."',
'".$strPersonEmail."',
)
";
```

into

```
$strSQL = "insert into person (PersonName,PersonEmail)
values (
'".$strPersonName."',
'".$strPersonEmail."'
)
";
```

Comment: i have not noticed that anyways thanks for point out my mistake :) i already ticked as useful and very soon i will accept your answer (in next 8 minutes) !'